# rotation of the camera is bad?

Tags: game-engine

I'm talking about the camera rotation via the look actuator, the frame rate FPS is good but when
moving the mouse to look the rotation is bad like when FPS is low the movement of the camera is good but rotation is bad, I don't know why.

Comment: Your explanation and question are not clear, please include more detail, images of the logic bricks and / or scripts that this uses.

Comment: I'm sorry about the bad explanation.